# Using TranslateAnimation to an item (from a ListView) doesn't takeout his parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm trying to use `TranslateAnimation` to move a profile picture to the top when item is clicked.

I found the correct position (x, y) but the profile picture doesn't come out of his item area.

I tried to use `bringToFront()` method but it doesn't work.

[image]

**My problem here**

[image]

**Code to animate my view**

```
public void animateContactAdding(View view) {
        View profileImage = view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_image_profile);

        int positionViewContact[] = {0, 0};
        profileImage.getLocationOnScreen(positionViewContact);

        int positionHeader[] = {0, 0};
        mRelativeLayoutContactHeader.getLocationOnScreen(positionHeader);

        float distanceBtwViews = (positionViewContact[1] - positionHeader[1]) * -1;

        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, distanceBtwViews);
        anim.setDuration(400);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        profileImage.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

**Item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_image_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle_image_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle_image_profile"
            android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:padding="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linear_layout_image_profile"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:lines="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linear_layout_image_profile"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.RalewaySemiBold"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are animating a entire layout. Try to apply the animation only on `ImageView` and see what happens:

```
public void animateContactAdding(View view) {
        int positionViewContact[] = {0, 0};
        profileImage.getLocationOnScreen(positionViewContact);

        int positionHeader[] = {0, 0};
        mRelativeLayoutContactHeader.getLocationOnScreen(positionHeader);

        float distanceBtwViews = (positionViewContact[1] - positionHeader[1]) * -1;

        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 2.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F
    );
        anim.setDuration(2000);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

Comment: My code doing this already. I'm animating just the profile pic without text.

Comment: Are you applying the animation in a layout? look at this line :  profileImage = view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_image_profile);

Comment: Oh, ok. Yes my item contains a `LinearLayout` who contains two `ImageView`. I tried directly on an `ImageView`, it looks exactly the same :-/

Comment: I passed my xml item file

Comment: I edited my answer, check if it works. Also, who calls the animateContactAdding method?

Comment: Its called from my adapter of my `recyclerView` (onClick)

Comment: hum.. It doesn't work :/ My view blinks now, that all :-/